# Continuous Integration with Talend ESB Open Studio

Tags: continuous-integration, talend, esb

I'm trying to add CI/CD to talend jobs (Talend ESB 7.3.1 Open Studio), I saw a few resources specially on the talend community website to do so, but on all of them they used the Talend CI Builder, but i can't find it. In one of those ressources it is told that it is embed in the studio files since v7.1.1

The builder is supposed to be installed here :

[image]

but I can't find it in my studio files
[image]

Is it because I use an open studio version of talend or the installation directory changed in the v7.3.1 ?

Thank you.

Comment: Find the answer by myself, the talend ci builder is only available on the cloud version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the answer by myself, the talend ci builder is only available on the cloud version.